# OpenXml SAX Approach

Tags: c#, openxml, sax

I am attempting to use the SAX approach to process large excel files. In my scenario, the user will map some columns from the spreadsheet, and we will get the data from each row based on the position of the cell and the value of the cell.

The process is working, but I was hoping for it to take less time. Does it appear that I am doing anything wrong?

```
        private string GetCellValue(Cell c, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>()
                .ElementAt(int.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText)).Text.Text;

        }

        return c.CellValue != null ? c.CellValue.InnerText : string.Empty;
```

}

```
        private void ProcessDocument()
    {
        using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(model.FileName, false))
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            var reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.ElementType != typeof(Row))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                rowCount++;
                reader.ReadFirstChild();
                var values = new ParcelValueImportValues();

                do
                {
                    if (reader.ElementType != typeof(Cell) || rowCount <= 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var c = (Cell)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
                    var location = GetCellLocation(c.CellReference);
                    var cellValue = GetCellValue(c, workbookPart);

                    if (location.Equals(hist.AssessmentRatio))
                    {
                        values.AssessmentRatio = cellValue;
                    }
                    else if (location.Equals(hist.AvImprovements))
                    {
                        values.AvImprovements = cellValue;
                    }
                    else if (location.Equals(hist.AvLand))
                    {
                        values.AvLand = cellValue;
                    }
                    else if (location.Equals(hist.FmvLand))
                    {
                        values.FmvLand = cellValue;
                    }
                    else if (location.Equals(hist.FmvImprovements))
                    {
                        values.FmvImprovements = cellValue;
                    }
                    else if (location.Equals(hist.ParcelNumber))
                    {
                        values.ParcelNumber = cellValue;
                    }

                } while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am wondering if I have inadvertently pulled in some DOM code.

Comment: Does anybody on this site respond to questions?

Comment: A late reply, but I believe workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable reads and re-reads the shared string table every time it is accessed.
Read it once outside the loop, and perhaps create a Dictionary out of it, then lookup the dictionary inside the loop.